# Mastermind check result python

Tags: python, algorithm

At the moment I am trying to make a mastermind-type code, like the game.
I am currently stuck on the bit where I am trying to check if the users guess is correct.

```py
colours = ["R","O","Y","G","B","I","V"]

n = 1
ans = random.choices(colours, k = 4)
print(*ans)
guess = input("what is your guess? ")

[guess[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(guess), n)]

guess = (guess.upper())

def check():
    correct = False
    right = 0
    wrong = 0
    if guess == ans:
        correct = True
    elif guess != ans:
        correct = False
        for i in range(0,(len(guess))):
            for x in range(0,(len(ans))):
                if guess[i] in ans:
                    wrong += 1

                    break


    print(right,"black pegs")
    print(wrong,"white pegs")
    return
check()
```

If `ans = "R O Y Y"`, and `guess = "R G O O"`
I would want the output to be

```py
1 white pegs
1 black pegs
```

what it actually gives me is

```py
3 white pegs
0 black pegs
```

white pegs means right colour, wrong place, black pegs means right colour, right place

How would I go around coding the black pegs?

Comment: @khelwood sorry just a mistake in post but its not in my code

Comment: The code here doesn't work the way you've said it does, it outputs 6 white pegs for `ans="R O Y Y"` and `guess = "R G O O"`

Comment: @NickA , Just double checked, and doesn't output what I said,(my bad, will fix) but not what u said either. What it outputs is `3 white pegs`

Comment: it outputs 6, it will output 3 if `ans="ROYY"` and `guess = "RGOO"` (note the lack of spaces, the ones you gave have spaces)

Comment: i will put what i have earlier in the code in the question now @NickA

Check now

Comment: Ah I see, `ans` is `["R","O","Y","Y"]` rather than a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161026/discussion-between-matt6297-and-nick-a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your problem is that you've not separated the logic into functions, that will make it easier to understand what needs done, so below I've separated the work into `count_white`, `count_black` and `check`.

The first thing you'll notice is that `["R","O","Y","Y"]` and `["R","G","O","O"]` gave 3 white pegs, that's because the `R` is being classed as white (although it should be black) and BOTH `O`s are being counted against the `O` in `ans` hence 3, the white pegs are in fact a whole lot harder to calculate than the black pegs.

The black pegs can be calculated using

```
black = 0
for i in range(len(guess)):
    if guess[i] == ans[i]:
        black += 1
```

or, more pythonic and in a function:

```
def count_black(ans, guess):
    return sum([ans[i] == guess[i] for i in range(len(ans))])
```

For the whites, you just need to check if a colour occurs in both lists, and if it does, remove it from `ans` so you don't check it more than once:

```
def count_white(ans, guess):
    temp_ans = ans[:]
    white = 0
    for i in guess:
        if i in temp_ans:
            temp_ans.remove(i)
            white += 1
    return white
```

Note that the above *ignores* if a peg is in the right position, that's okay, because we know how many are in the right position from the black count.

Now that these have been moved into functions your `check` can simply be:

```
def check(ans, guess):
    white = count_white(ans, guess)
    black = count_black(ans, guess)
    white -= black

    print(black,"black pegs")
    print(white,"white pegs")

    return black == 4
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> check(["R","O","Y","Y"],["R","G","O","O"])
1 black pegs
1 white pegs
False
```

Note that the returned `False` is whether or not it was correct.

Thus all your code can be written as:

```
import random
colours = ["R","O","Y","G","B","I","V"]
ans = [random.choice(colours) for i in range(4)]
print(''.join(ans))

def count_white(ans, guess):
    temp_ans = ans[:]
    pegs = 0
    for i in guess:
        if i in temp_ans:
            temp_ans.remove(i)
            pegs += 1
    return pegs

def count_black(ans, guess):
    return sum([ans[i] == guess[i] for i in range(len(ans))])

def check(ans, guess):
    white = count_white(ans, guess)
    black = count_black(ans, guess)
    white -= black

    print(black,"black pegs")
    print(white,"white pegs")

    return black == 4

guess = []
while guess != ans:
    guess = list(input("what is your guess?").upper())
    check(ans, guess)
```

Comment: in our chat, I asked you a question about the code you gave me. Please can you help me with it @NickA

Comment: @matt6297 No, sorry, I don't have time, I suggest that you study the following topics: functions, lists/list comprehensions and `for` loops

Answer (score 0):

```
guess[i] == ans
```

Shouldn't it be?

```
guess[i] == ans[x]
```

Because you compare chars, not char to whole string :)

And I'm not sure if this actually solves your problem, since you have to keep track which colors you have counted and which not yet from now on

Answer (score 0):

In fact it is trivial for black pegs, but slightly more complicated for white pegs, because your current algorythm does not correctly process repeated colors. So IMHO you could examine each element of the guess 2 times, first for right color at right place and second for right color at wrong place *removing the found element* to avoid counting it multiple times. A simple way would be to take a modifiable copy before the loop.

Assuming `ans` and `guess` are both iterable, you code could become:

```
def check(ans, guess):
    correct = False
    right = 0
    wrong = 0
    if guess == ans:
        correct = True
        right = len(guess)
    else:
        correct = False
        test = list(ans)      # take a modifiable copy
        for i, colour in enumerate(guess):
            if ans[i] == colour:     # is it at the correct place?
                right += 1
            elif colour in test:     # if not is it present?
                test.remove(colour)  # count it only one
                wrong += 1
    print(right,"black pegs")
    print(wrong,"white pegs")
    return correct
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish with your code because you didn't specify things like what happens if a character appears more than once in guess but only appears once in ans. Anyway, this should give you the output you are looking for.

```
def check():
    ans = "ROYY"
    guess = "RGOO"
    correct = False
    right = 0
    wrong = 0
    if guess == ans:
        correct = True

    for i in ans:
        j = 0
        while(j < len(guess)):
            if i in guess and i == guess[j]:
                right += 1
                break
            elif i in guess and i != guess[j]:
                wrong += 1
                break
            elif i not in guess:
                break;
        j += 1

    print(right,"black pegs")
    print(wrong,"white pegs")
    return
check()
```